# Is Texting Someone the Word “Allah” in the toilet bad?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, sin

If you were texting someone a sentence which had the word “Allah” in it. Is this classed as wrong and if so, what should this person do (repent how?) This person didn’t say “Allah” out loud but it was texted, is this an issue? if so, how can this person repent?

Comment: This was texted unintentionally and without knowing but when He realised he switched off the phone completely. Is this an issue? Will i be punished for this? Is there any way to repent?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but I was taught that it's best to avoid any form if talking (texting included) in the toilet. It's a place of filth occupied by Shaitan and jinns, and you want to get out as quickly as possible.

Comment: Why are you asking "who to repent". You should know that it is a small sin and almost all small sins are forgive just by saying "astagfiruallh".

Answer (score -1):

**I** think it is a sin.

You can just say *astagfiruallh*